# Move an uploaded image to a IIS virtual directory using PHP

Tags: php, iis, virtual-directory

I am building a page that allows a user to enter data about a particular piece of equipment as well as upload an image of that equipment to a server so that it can be shown when other users query that particular piece of equipment. The equipment will be tracked by serial number.

After a user enters all the equipment info, chooses the image location and clicks submit....the equipment data is written to a MySQL db the image is renamed with the equipment's serial number and stored in a folder named 'uploads' located in the sites root directory.

Everything works perfectly! However, now I need to start storing the images on a different server so that they can also be accessed by our GIS system.

We setup a folder on the other server.... //trxshares/GIS/transformer_pictures. My IT department setup a IIS virtual directory pointing to the trxshares folder in the root of the data entry site.

Here is the working code for uploading to the local folder uploads/:

```
     if(isset($_FILES['image']))
        {
            if($_FILES['image']['name'] != NULL)
            {
                $errors= array();
                $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
                $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
                $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
                $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
                $exp = explode(".", $_FILES['image']['name']);
                $file_ext = strtolower(end($exp));

                $extensions= array("jpg");

                if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false)
                   $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a .jpg file.";

                if($file_size > 4096000)
                   $errors[]='File size must be less than 4 MB';

                if(empty($errors)==true)
                {
                  move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$SerialNo.".".$file_ext);
                }
                else
                    print_r($errors);
            }
```

Again, the code above works perfectly.

In this next block, I try moving the file to the virtual directory and get errors:

```
    if(isset($_FILES['image']))
        {
            if($_FILES['image']['name'] != NULL)
            {
                $errors= array();
                $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
                $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
                $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
                $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
                $exp = explode(".", $_FILES['image']['name']);
                $file_ext = strtolower(end($exp));

                $extensions= array("jpg");

                if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false)
                   $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a .jpg file.";

                if($file_size > 4096000)
                   $errors[]='File size must be less than 4 MB';

                if(empty($errors)==true)
                {
                  move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."\\transformer_pictures\\".$SerialNo.".".$file_ext);
                }
                else
                    print_r($errors);
            }
```

and get this error:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\lusapps\transformer_pictures\1684271793.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\lusapps\app\power\power-transformers.php on line 398 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\phpA27E.tmp' to 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\lusapps\transformer_pictures\1684271793.jpg' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\lusapps\app\power\power-transformers.php on line 398*

I cant seem to figure out how to reference the virtual directory correctly....any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Check the permissions of the destination folder. can the php process write to it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using only the name of the virtual directory. For example if your virtual directory is transformer_pictures, then use /transformer_pictures by itself without the $SERVER[Document_Root].

Another approach could be to use a share path on the other server. //other_server_path/transformer_pictures, just make sure the Application Pool user has permissions to that directory.